# Questions about Jelastic automatic downsizing upsizing

Tags: jelastic

I would like to know how fast can Jelastic add new resources to a node in case we receive a peak of visitors.
BTW is there a way to have some extra resources enabled in advance when expect a peak of visitors?

Comment: > is there a way to have some extra resources enabled in advance when expect a peak of visitors? 
Just set a higher scaling limit (dynamic cloudlets) in advance. You will pay only for actually used resources https://docs.jelastic.com/pricing-model.

Answer (score 3):

In almost all mayor platforms who offer IAAS , a restart is needed in order to increase or decrease ram, cpu and disk.

But Jelastic offer an automatic and immediately resources allocation as it says in official documentation:

> **How It Works:** The resources are allocated immediately without delays or negative impact on your application

Also, in this [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E-NX9s0RiA) a **peak of visitors** scenario is simulated and wen can see an **immediate** increase and decrease of resources in the form of a [cloudet](https://docs.jelastic.com/cloudlet)

Official source : https://docs.jelastic.com/automatic-vertical-scaling